# webpack can't parse material ui button in a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to bundle some React components with webpack.

But when I launch **webpack --mode=development**, i get this error :

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> | const OwnButton = () => {
> |   return (     <Button color='secondary' variant='outlined'

This is my webpack config :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   entry: './src/app.js', // relative path
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), // absolute path
      filename: 'js/bundle.js' // file name
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

This is my app.js config :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import OwnButton from './Components/OwnButton';

const template = <Button>Hello from react jsx</Button>;

ReactDOM.render(template, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<OwnButton/>, document.getElementById('React-OwnButton'));
```

And the wanted component (index.jsx) :

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const OwnButton = () => {
  return (
    <Button color='secondary' variant='outlined'>
      Hello from my own component
    </Button>
  );
};

export default OwnButton;
```

And my .babelrc

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

I don't understand how the  call l.6 on app.js can work but not the  on index.jsx l.6.

Where must I put the loader for this, in babel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you configured the Babel Loader to only intervene for `.js` files.

Try changing: `test: /\.js$/` -> `test: /\.((js)|(jsx))$/`

This will make the loader work for `.jsx` files too.